# android alarmmanager multiple alarms, one overwrites the other?

Tags: java, android

I've searched posts for answers to my question but haven't found anything that solves my problem. I'm trying to set 3 different alarms using one AlarmSettings class.  When I set two alarms, the second one takes precedence over the first and the first never goes off.  I think it may have to do with my pending intent...  I'm really new to android and would greatly appreciate the help.  Here's my code for setting the alarms:

```
public void setAlarm() {

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, timepicker.getCurrentHour());
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, timepicker.getCurrentMinute());
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

        if (timepicker.getCurrentHour() < calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)) { //if the alarm hour is less than the current hour
            calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);                                     //then add 24 hours (1 DATE or Day)                 
        }

        //Create the text that we want to set the TextView alarmtime to in Main
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        if (timepicker.getCurrentHour() > 12) {
            sb.append(timepicker.getCurrentHour() - 12);
        } else {
            sb.append(timepicker.getCurrentHour());
        }
        sb.append(":");
        sb.append(timepicker.getCurrentMinute());
        sb.append(" ");
        if (timepicker.getCurrentHour() > 12) {
            sb.append("pm");
        } else {
            sb.append("am");
        }

        if (((GlobalVariables)getApplication()).getCurrentAlarmBeingEdited() == 1) {
            ((GlobalVariables)getApplication()).setAlarm1Cal(calendar);
            Main.alarmTime1.setText(sb);

            Intent intent1 = new Intent(AlarmSettings.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
            intent1.putExtra("alarm_num", ((GlobalVariables)getApplication()).getCurrentAlarmBeingEdited());
            PendingIntent pendingIntent1 = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent1, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

            alarmmanager1.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent1);

        } else if (((GlobalVariables)getApplication()).getCurrentAlarmBeingEdited() == 2) {
            ((GlobalVariables)getApplication()).setAlarm2Cal(calendar);
            Main.alarmTime2.setText(sb);

            Intent intent2 = new Intent(AlarmSettings.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
            intent2.putExtra("alarm_num", ((GlobalVariables)getApplication()).getCurrentAlarmBeingEdited());
            PendingIntent pendingIntent2 = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent2, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

            alarmmanager2.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent2);

        } else if (((GlobalVariables)getApplication()).getCurrentAlarmBeingEdited() == 3) {
            ((GlobalVariables)getApplication()).setAlarm3Cal(calendar);
            Main.alarmTime3.setText(sb);

            Intent intent3 = new Intent(AlarmSettings.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
            intent3.putExtra("alarm_num", ((GlobalVariables)getApplication()).getCurrentAlarmBeingEdited());
            PendingIntent pendingIntent3 = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent3, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

            alarmmanager3.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent3);
        }

        finish();

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "system time: " + System.currentTimeMillis() + "\n" + "picked time: " + calendar.getTimeInMillis(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();      
    }
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent1 = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent1, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
```

change the 0 attribute to an id for your alarm, for example you have three alarms,

repeat the above code with 0,1,2.

this way they won't override each other.

Comment: You welcome, you can mark it as answer to be obvious and helpful for other people with same your problem. Good luck in coding!

Comment: Please don't approve [such suggested edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/950604). See my comment.

Comment: if 0 attribute changes to any random id for alarm.. can it's work exactly the same as above you say @HeshamSaeed