# Setting up reminder taking different date and time from database

Tags: android

Hi I am working on a application where I am getting reminder details from user as reminder Date,time,title,note and repeat option. Then storing those in database. I used alarm manager class to set alarm it is working perfect but only if there is one reminder. I simply used cursor to fetch date and time from database,but the problems comes when there are multiple date and time and set reminder on those??? What should I do? Please help me. Suggest something or tutorial will be great idea. Thanks in advance!

Comment: maybe post some code ?

Comment: can you post some code and let see if we can help?

Answer (score 0):

one solution is sort those reminders based on time incrementally. and every time you execute one reminder create a new one on alarm manager. or you can set multiple alarms:
check this out : [multiple alarms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10271417/android-alarmmanager-multiple-alarms-one-overwrites-the-other)